# How can I install pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to install pyplot using `pip install pyplot` in the command prompt while it was installing by mistake I closed command prompt. I tried to install pyplot using the same command again, but it is not installing.

[image: Kindly find the error in this image]

How can I install pyplot?

Comment: And never post image of code or errors. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

pyplot is part of a matplotlib.
In order to install pyplot you should install matplotlib

`pip install matplotlib`

So you can **"import matplotlib.pyplot"**

Answer (score 1):

You can go to https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib to see and install the version you want.
Then you can import the pylot

```python
from matplotlib import pyplot
```